# Spring Boot, Spring Security specify redirect login url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

At my Spring Boot application I need to implement a following scenario:

Anonymous User visits the following page: `http://example.com/product-a.html`
This User wants to ask a question about this product. It can be done at another page, located by the following address: `http://example.com/product-a/ask`. User press `Ask Question` button at the `http://example.com/product-a.html` and login/registration popup is shown. After successful login User should be automatically redirected to `http://example.com/product-a/ask` (but currently with a default Spring Security implementation User are redirecting back to the page originator `http://example.com/product-a.html`)

How to properly with Spring Boot/Spring Security implement/configure this redirect ?

**UPDATED**

This is my web security config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // @formatter:off
    http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

    http
        .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/v1.0/**", "/logout")
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()

        .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
        //Anyone can access the urls
        .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/signin/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/v1.0/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority(Permission.READ_ACTUATOR_DATA)
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl(logoutSuccessUrl)
                .permitAll();
    // @formatter:on
}
```

I use OAuth2/JWT + Implicit Flow for AngularJS client

Comment: What does pressing the "Ask Question" button do? Does it popup the Login/Registration by itself or does it just do a get request to http://example.com/product-a/ask?

Comment: @Currently I only plan to implement this for "Ask Question" button. But I have already implemented both approaches (popup and dedicated page) for another pages. So, it will be good to support both of them for this case.

Comment: @zakariaamine I have added my config. I use OAuth2/JWT + Implicit Flow for my UI client written at AngularJS

Comment: A first guess: did you try adding `.formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/product-a/ask")`

Comment: @zakariaamine I think it will work but it will redirect all of the login requests(from any page) to the mentioned one but I have to control where the User should be redirected because the `successUrl` will differ from one page to another.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use spring's default /login processing url, but create your own e.g /mylogin in a controller. And then you can inject the HttpServletRequest in the method and take the action based on the context of the request for example:

```
@PostMapping("/mylogin")
public ResponseEntity<> processingLogingURL(HttpServletRequest request){
   // switch bases on the request URL after checking security off course
   switch(request.getRequestURL()){

    //redirect based on the caller URL 
  }

}
```

and finally change your  `.loginProcessingUrl("/login")` to `.loginProcessingUrl("/mylogin")`